# Ruby bad array to Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a ugly array that looks like this

```
["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]", "advert 4", "[1404915231]", "advert 5", "[1404915231]", "advert 6", "[1404915231]", "advert 7", "[1404915231]", "advert 8", "[1404915231]", "advert 9", "[1404915231]"]
```

I've tried to get it to look like this but I have been unsuccessful.

```
{advert1: [1404915231, 1404920520], advert4: [1404915231]}
```

Thanks

Comment: where is other data? only 1 and 4 ? and rest ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ArupRakshit More mysteriously, where does 1 come from?

Comment: @sawa This another example of Guess, that we met earlier also.. Really frustrating. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit A lazy question deserves a lazy answer. You don't need to make your answer detailed.

Comment: This is like: "Suppose you have a sequence that begins 1,5,12,16.  What is the next number in the sequence?"

Comment: Ugly? That array looks pretty darn cute to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way(if it helps you) :-

```
require 'yaml'

arr = [
       "advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
       "advert 4", "[1404915231]", "advert 5",
       "[1404915231]", "advert 6", "[1404915231]",
       "advert 7", "[1404915231]", "advert 8",
       "[1404915231]", "advert 9", "[1404915231]"
     ]

Hash[arr.each_slice(2).map { |a, b| [a.gsub(/\s+/,'').to_sym, YAML.load(b)] }]
 # => {:advert0=>[1404915231, 1404920520],
 #     :advert4=>[1404915231],
 #     :advert5=>[1404915231],
 #     :advert6=>[1404915231],
 #     :advert7=>[1404915231],
 #     :advert8=>[1404915231],
 #     :advert9=>[1404915231]}
```

[`Enumerable#each_slice(2)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) - Is sending 2 items from the collection, to the [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) block. Now OP wants, *string* to be converted as *symbols*. Thus, I used first, to removes the white spaces in between *strings*. It is done by [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) method. I passed the *regex*, `/\s+/` as an Argument to the method `#gsub`, which as per the *regex*, will find each *white space* and replace them with *empty strings(`''`)*. That means

```
"advert 0".gsub(/\s+/,'') # => "advert0"
```

Now as OP wants, all keys to be *symbols*, I apply [`String#to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym).

```
"advert0".to_sym # => :advert0
```

So finally, I need to covert all *string arrays* to *array*, thus [`YAML::load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#module-YAML-label-Usage) will be helpful.

```
 YAML::load "[1404915231, 1404920520]" # => [1404915231, 1404920520]
```

Till now what I said, will give us -

```
arr.each_slice(2).map { |a, b| [a.gsub(/\s+/,'').to_sym, YAML.load(b)] }
 # => [[:advert0, [1404915231, 1404920520]],
 #     [:advert4, [1404915231]],
 #     [:advert5, [1404915231]],
 #     [:advert6, [1404915231]],
 #     [:advert7, [1404915231]],
 #     [:advert8, [1404915231]],
 #     [:advert9, [1404915231]]]
```

Now, I will make it a `Hash`. Look this [`Hash[ key, value, ... ] → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
Hash[:a,[1],:b, [2,3]] # => {:a=>[1], :b=>[2, 3]}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would be nice if, when providing a very complicated one-liner, you explained what's going on. You're doing several things here that aren't at all obvious to beginners. Stack Overflow's purpose is to help people *learn* programming techniques, which means it's our job to *teach* them, not to just throw a pile of code at them and say "This works!"

Comment: @Jordan It's not our job to do anything here. We are doing this for free. Anyone can contribute to the extent that they want to. Don't let the OP think they can expect too much. Facing a well written question, someone might voluntarily want to write a detailed answer. Facing a sloppy question, someone may not want to answer at all, or may want to answer half-way.

Comment: @sawa Just because "anyone can contribute to the extent they want to" doesn't mean that every contribution is good. It's unfortunate that you see people seeking help ("OP") as adversaries who shouldn't "expect too much" instead of colleagues that we should help to the best of our abilities. As the FAQ says, "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: @Jordan Just give me a moment. I am translating the code to plain English. It will take time.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I noticed your first edits and I appreciate your taking the time to turn a *correct* answer into a *great* answer!

Comment: @Jordan I will do some few edits.. My mom is calling, I need to talk with her first over phone.. So  :-)

Comment: Wonderful! If I could give you two upvotes I would. :)

Answer (score 2):

Arup gives a great answer, but if you're looking for alternatives, here are some thoughts I had:

### Break down the problem

Let's break down the problem. We have `ugly_array`, and we want to use its even elements (`"advert 0"`, `"advert 2"`) as keys in a Hash, and its odd elements as the corresponding values. We want to transform both the keys (into symbols) and the values (into arrays of numbers) on the way.

### Create a (temporary) Hash

A useful method in Ruby is [`Hash[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), which will create a Hash using its odd arguments as keys and even arguments as values. For example:

```
Hash[ :foo, 1, :bar, 2 ]
# => { :foo => 1, :bar => 2 }
```

In order to use the items in `ugly_array` as separate arguments, we put `*` ("splat") before it:

```
ugly_hash = Hash[ *ugly_array ]
```

This is equivalent to `Hash[ "advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]", "advert 4", ... ]`, and it gives us this Hash:

```
{ "advert 0" => "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
  "advert 4" => "[1404915231]",
  "advert 5" => "[1404915231]",
  # ...
}
```

### Transform the keys

Now we need to transform the keys and values. First, the keys. You want to turn the string `"advert 0"` into the symbol `:advert0`, which we can do like this:

```
"advert 0".gsub(" ", "").to_sym
 # => :advert0
```

To clarify [`gsub(" ", "")`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) replaces all spaces (`" "`) with nothing, which effectively removes them. We could also use a regular expression like `/\s+/`, but it looks like the extra flexibility isn't really needed here. Now we have the string `"advert0"`, and [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym) converts it into the symbol `:advert0`.

### Transform the values

We want to turn a string like `"[1404915231, 1404920520]"` into an array of numbers like `[1404915231, 1404920520]`. There are a lot of different ways to do this, but one way that doesn't require using a module like JSON or YAML is this:

```
"[1404915231, 1404920520]".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
# => [ 1404915231, 1404920520 ]
```

This does two things. First, [`scan(/\d+/)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) uses a regular expression to find sequences of consecutive digits (`\d`) in the string and returns them as an array, yielding an array of strings: `["1404915231", "1404920520"]`. Then we use [`map(&:to_i)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to call the [`to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) method on each of the strings, yielding an array of numbers.

### Transform the temporary Hash

Now that we know how to transform the keys and values, we can take our temporary Hash and build a new, transformed Hash from it. There are other ways to do this, but I'm fond of [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). Suppose we do this:

```
ugly_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), hsh|
  hsh[key] = val
end
```

Inside the block, `hsh` is the new, empty Hash (`{}`) we gave as the argument to `each_with_object`, and in each iteration we add `val` to it with the key `key`. This yields:

```
{ "advert 0" => "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
  "advert 4" => "[1404915231]",
  # ...
}
```

It looks exactly the same! But you can probably see that since we have `key` and `val` inside the block, we can transform them before using them.

### Bring it all together

```
pretty_hash = Hash[ *ugly_array ].each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), hsh|
  key = key.tr(" ", "").to_sym
  val = val.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  hsh[key] = val
end
```

As you can see, this is the same code, except inside the block we're transforming `key` and `val` before using them to add an element to the Hash. And it gives us just what we're looking for:

```
p pretty_hash
# => { :advert0 => [ 1404915231, 1404920520 ],
#      :advert4 => [ 1404915231 ],
#      :advert5 => [ 1404915231 ],
#      ...
#    }
```

Apart from being relatively readable and not requiring external libraries, this method has the distinct advantage of iterating over the original data exactly once and performing only one (composite) operation on each key and value.

If you're so inclined, you can reduce the inside of the block to a single line, but be aware of how it impacts readability:

```
pretty_hash = Hash[*ugly_array].each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), hsh|
  hsh[ key.tr(" ", "").to_sym ] = val.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
end
```

I hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed you want the result:

```
{ advert0: [1404915231, 1404920520], advert4: [1404915231] }
```

That is, I assume you meant `advert0` where you wrote `advert1`; specifically, that you wish to select those pairs `"advert x", arr` (`arr` being an array) that correspond to given values of `x` (here `0` and `4`) and convert the collection of those pairs to a hash.  If this is not want you want to do, you need read no further.

You could do this as follows:

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, *vals_at)
  arr.each_slice(2)
     .map {|s1,s2|
       [s1.split.last.to_i,[s1.tr(' ','').to_sym, s2.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)]]}
     .to_h
     .values_at(*vals_at)
     .to_h
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
       "advert 4", "[1404915231]",
       "advert 5", "[1404915231]"
      ]
```

(We don't need the rest of `arr`.)

```
doit(arr, 0, 4)
  #=> {:advert0=>[1404915231, 1404920520], :advert4=>[1404915231]}
```

**Explanation**

For the value of `arr` above, let:

```
b = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
  #                  "advert 4", "[1404915231]",
  #                  "advert 5", "[1404915231]"]:each_slice(2)>

c = b.map
  #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]",
  #                            "advert 4", "[1404915231]",
  #                            "advert 5", "[1404915231]"]:each_slice(2)>:map>
```

`c` may be thought of as a "compound" enumerator. When we add a block, `each` will pass each value of the following array into the block:

```
c.to_a
  #=> [["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]"],
  #    ["advert 4", "[1404915231]"],
  #    ["advert 5", "[1404915231]"]]
```

Note

```
b.to_a == c.to_a #=> true
```

Next,

```
d = c.each { |s1,s2| [s1.split.last.to_i,
                     [s1.tr(' ','').to_sym, s2.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)]] }
  #=> [[0, [:advert0, [1404915231, 1404920520]]],
  #    [4, [:advert4, [1404915231]]],
  #    [5, [:advert5, [1404915231]]]]
```

Note that `c.each` is equivalent to `b.map`:

```
d == b.map { |s1,s2| [s1.split.last.to_i,
                      [s1.tr(' ','').to_sym, s2.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)]] }
  #=> true
```

Let's pause a moment to see what's going on here.  The first value the enumerator `c` passes into the block (`["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]"]`) is split into the two block variables by disambiguation:

```
s1 #=> "advert 0"
s2 #=> "[1404915231, 1404920520]"
```

Then:

```
s1.split.last.to_i
  #=> 0
r = s2.scan(/\d+/)
  #=> ["1404915231", "1404920520"]
r.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [1404915231, 1404920520]
```

Ergo, the first element passed into the block:

```
["advert 0", "[1404915231, 1404920520]"]
```

is mapped to:

```
[0,[1404915231, 1404920520]]
```

Similarly, the second and the third elements of `c` are respectively mapped to:

```
[4=>[:advert4, [1404915231]]
```

and

```
[5=>[:advert5, [1404915231]]
```

Now that we have `d`,

```
e = d.to_h # or Hash[d] for Ruby versions < 2.0
  #=> {0=>[:advert0, [1404915231, 1404920520]],
  #    4=>[:advert4, [1404915231]],
  #    5=>[:advert5, [1404915231]]}
```

Aha! Now you can see why I constructed `e` as I did:

```
f = e.values_at(0,4)
  #=> [[:advert0, [1404915231, 1404920520]], [:advert4, [1404915231]]]

f.to_h
  #=> {:advert0=>[1404915231, 1404920520], :advert4=>[1404915231]}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you construct the intermediate Hash `e` when you could just construct the Array `f` in your `map` block without an intermediate step. Also it's worth noting that `Array#to_h` is only available in Ruby 2.1+.

Comment: @Jordan, I don't see a better way to get from `d` to `f`.  Please elaborate.  I mentioned `to_h`'s birth date in a comment where I define `e`.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to select specific keys from the data—I think he wants to transform all of the data, despite his somewhat misleading example. Whether or not he does, though, there are several ways this can be done better: I've written a few of them here: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/7d3aec317ee47691731f Regardless I think none of these is ideal, because even in the best case we perform several operations on each item. In my answer you can see that it's possible to iterate over the original data exactly once and perform no more than one operation on each key and value.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I clarified my premise at the beginning of my answer. Thank you for taking the time to work on my code.  Alternative 4 at github is interesting (but I don't see why you lazified). Why don't OP's clarify their questions when readers ask/beg them to do so?? I'll never understand that.